# Loading Google map blank with console errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi am trying to get a google map to show up on a page in a ruby on rails app but I'm getting the following errors. I'm struggling to understand how the whole process works. I think it has to do with the script tag but can't figure it out.

gmaps.js file in javascript folder:

```
/* Options for Google maps */


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
});
```

html.erb:

```
<%# Google map %>
    <div>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px;">
            </div>
    </div>
```

Script in application html:

```
<%-# Google map script tag-%>

   <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Console errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined is referring to this line:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas')
```

This error means that Ruby doesn't know what google is because you have not defined it.

Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function  is referring to this line:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD6jUOjpSNBqs3jVSCyZiXU6On1NqPIS6I&callback=initMap">
```

so the callback is being called but your application hasn't defined what the initMap function is.

Are you using a gem to do this?  If so which one?

Comment: That got me on the right path!  I'm not using gems at the mo because I want to understand what's going on under the hood first.